# http POST from body using multiple parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a method in ASP.Net Web API Controller as follows -

```
public string addNewTask([FromBody]TaskListModels _newTask)
        {
            DataTable _newTaskDataTable = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString.ToString());
                sqlHelper.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskId", _newTask.taskId);
                //sqlHelper.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
                sqlHelper.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskDetails", _newTask.taskDetails);
                sqlHelper.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyId", _newTask.companyId);
                sqlHelper.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dueDate", _newTask.dueDate);
                _newTaskDataTable = sqlHelper.ReturnDataTableFromStoredProcedure("[dbo].[MYSP]");
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SQL ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            }

            return "String";
        }
```

Where TaskListModels is a class with some properties as follows.

```
public class TaskListModels
    {
        public int taskId { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string taskDetails { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public string dueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to post some data from an Angular service as follows -

```
 public addTask(_newTask: any) {
 console.log('Service - TaskListService : Method - addTask : Params - ' + JSON.stringify(_newTask))

this._requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: this.addNewtaskApiUrl,
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(_newTask)
    });
    console.log('ADD New - POST Request Query : ' + JSON.stringify(this._requestOptions));
    return this._http.request(new Request(this._requestOptions)).map(this._httpExtractDataService.extractData).catch(this._httpErrorHandlerService.handleError); 
}
```

The data appears in the browser console as follows but it is not hitting my controller method -

```
POST Request Query : {"method":1,"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"body":"{\"taskId\":4,\"taskDetails\":\"Working with Avi for accounting platform project setup\",\"companyId\":4,\"dueDate\":\"2017-05-16\"}","url":"http://localhost:56250/api/Dashboard/addNewTask","withCredentials":null,"responseType":null}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you call `addTask`?

Comment: addTask is a method in the service.I am calling it in a component like this -

 public updateTask(newTask: any) {
   this._taskListService.addTask(this.newTask);
        }

Comment: is the http request fired? do you see it in network tab of your browser ? also, that ASP.NET `addNewTask`, is it registered as an `POST` endpoint?

Comment: Yup. It is fired...but not reaching till controller method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are by default cold. You need to `subscribe` to an observable to actually  make a request:

```
this._taskListService.addTask(this.newTask).subscribe((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @echonax...It worked, thank you so much. You made my day dear...

Comment: @AmitAnand Glad I could help :-)

Comment: @AmitAnand, since this answer helped you, please accept the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, so that question is marked as solved :) Here's how if it's unclear: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235